# How to include device id, ip address, user's location and other stuff which is unique to user in Express API in authentication middleware

Tags: express, authentication, authorization

[image]

I'm developing an Express application and aiming to implement the highest level of security possible. In this system, I want to ensure that even if a hacker somehow obtains a bearer token, they are unable to access backend APIs on behalf of the user. To achieve this, I plan to incorporate checks for the bearer token, IP address, device ID, user's geographic location, and any other unique identifiers tied to the user.

Furthermore, I want to implement a feature where users are immediately notified if someone logs into the website from a different device ID, IP address, or geographic location.

Could anyone provide guidance on creating middleware in Express to accomplish these security measures? Additionally, are there any existing libraries or frameworks that facilitate these functionalities?

I attempted to pass the device ID, user's location, and IP address in the API headers. However, I could not figure out how to do it.

While exploring potential solutions, I came across an open-source authentication system called Keycloak (https://www.keycloak.org/) that seems to offer the features you're looking for. Keycloak provides mechanisms to incorporate various security checks, including device ID, user location, and IP address verification.

Although Keycloak presents a comprehensive solution, I want to code and build the authentication system independently.